# Is it possible to Create/Attach a snapshot schedule using Deployment Manager?

Tags: google-deployment-manager

I have a google cloud Deployment Manager template which creates a load-balanced application.

Traffic is distributed to VM instances that are created through an autoscaler.

I want to attach a snapshot schedule to the disk of every instance created by the autoscaler. Can I do this in the Deployment Manager template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment Manager is currently only offering [support for API methods](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types#apis_for_supported_resources) regarding disks (`compute.alpha.disk`, `compute.beta.disk` and `compute.v1.disk`). Although they support [creating disk from snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/insert), specifically scheduling should be included in `compute.*.snapshot`, which is not supported.

What you can do instead, is to schedule the snapshots either directly calling the API using the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries), or using gcloud from another client machine.

Essentially, this particular feature is not yet mapped in Deployment Manager. To determine which APIs are available, you can do:

`gcloud deployment-manager types list`

And check the API documentation for each to see if your particular feature is in one of them.

Comment: That makes sense. Since snapshots must be scheduled when a new instance is created I suppose that my options are to run gcloud from the same instance or maybe publish an event to Pub/Sub and then process this event to schedule the snapshot. Thanks a lot!